Calling procedure with different times as input parameter
I have Postgresql procedure
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE chk()
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

FOR i IN 1 .. 2
LOOP
   call InsrtMockdata();
END LOOP;

END;
$BODY$; 

This procedure runs 2 times and exits
I there any way I can achieve the same by replacing
the range  FOR i IN 1 .. 2  as paramaters where I can ran the procedure domically how many time I need

Yes, just add a input parameter as
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE chk(times integer)
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..times
    LOOP
       call InsrtMockdata();
    END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$;

Then call it
DO $$   
BEGIN
    call chk(3);
END $$;


Why the DO-statement? It's just extra code without any benefits. call chk(3); does exactly the same.

You're right @FrankHeikens it's a code snippet that I use to test procedures using variables (DECLARE) in a call, other way is unnecessary.
